# RavenDB LoadAsync. Can't catch exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb, async-await

I have a simple async method that loads an entity asynchronously using LoadAsync. I can't catch exceptions thrown by the async call. Debugging just leads to 'AggregateException was unhandled by user code.' I'm using RavenDB Client 2.0.2375.

How can I catch these exceptions?

Here's the method:

```
 private async Task<Dummy> GetDummyAsync(string id)
    {
        using (var session = docStore.OpenAsyncSession())
        {
            try
            {
                var dummy = await session.LoadAsync<Dummy>(id);
                return dummy;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Here's the exception:

System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassc.b*_9() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 128
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 351
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.<InternalReadResponseStringAsync>b__8(Task`1 task) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 128
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
       InnerException:

Comment: This will probably help you find the solution: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/11/01/csharp5-async-exceptions

Comment: Do you see same behavior **without** attaching **debugger** ?

Comment: Perhaps exception is thrown by `OpenAsyncSession`? What is stack trace? What is in the `InnerExceptions` ?

Comment: The exceptions change depending on what I'm doing. If I request an invalid document they're HTTP 404 exceptions. I can catch the exceptions with a UnhandledExceptionTrapper but that's really not what I want to do. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but at 4 in the morning I'm starting to think there's a bug in raven. I'll dig into this more tomorrow.

Comment: The inner exception doesn't matter. For testing I just load a document that doesn't exist and the inner exception is a System.Net.WebException: " Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: @yk1 You're correct. The exception was being thrown by OpenAsyncSession. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior your seeing is valid, and is not because you couldn't catch the exception.  It's because the exception was already caught for you.

In RavenDB, if you try to load a document that doesn't exist, the `Load` or `LoadAsync` methods will return `null`.  They will not throw an exception.

When you are debugging, you are seeing that under the hood a `WebException` is thrown when the HTTP response comes back as 404.  That exception is handled.  You should see it in the output window as a "First Chance Exception".

This is all normal behavior.  If you want to check that you can catch exceptions, try something that will actually throw an exception.  Perhaps load a document of one type while trying to cast it into another.  That will certainly throw an exception.